# Android: Save the Paint paths to device / sharedpreferences

Tags: android, canvas, path, sharedpreferences

I am working on a painting app, of which inside the doodleView the drawn paths and its respective colors and width are stored as follows:

### Variables

```
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private Map<Path, Integer> colorsMap = new HashMap<Path, Integer>();
private Map<Path, Integer> widthMap = new HashMap<Path, Integer>();
private Map<Path, Integer> styleMap = new HashMap<Path, Integer>();
```

### MotionEvent

```
   private void touch_start(float x, float y) 
   {
       undonePaths.clear();
       mPath.reset();
       mPath.moveTo(x, y);
       mX = x;
       mY = y;
   }

   private void touch_move(float x, float y) 
   {
       float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
       float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
       if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
       {
           mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
           mX = x;
           mY = y;

           startdrawing = true;
       }
   }

   private void touch_up() 
   {
       mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);      
       mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, Utilities.mPaint); 
       paths.add(mPath);
       colorsMap.put(mPath,selectedColor);
       widthMap.put(mPath,selectedWidth);
       styleMap.put(mPath, selectedStyle);
       mPath = new Path(); 
   }

   public void onClickUndo() 
   { 
       if (paths.size()>0) 
        { 
           undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
           invalidate();
        }      
       else 
       {
           String xx = getContext().getString(R.string.toast_nothing_to_undo);
           Activity activity = (Activity) context_new;
           Utilities.custom_toast(activity, ""+ xx, "gone!", "Short"); 
       }
    }

   public void onClickRedo()
   {
       if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
       { 
           paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)); 
           invalidate();
       } 
       else 
       {
           String xx = getContext().getString(R.string.toast_nothing_to_redo);
           Activity activity = (Activity) context_new;
           Utilities.custom_toast(activity, ""+ xx, "gone!", "Short"); 
       }
    }
```

### Question:

The above codes are working very well. However, back from the home button / notification bar, sometimes the paths are released from memory.

I would like to ask how could I save the paths such that the paths such that the paths can be redrawn onCreate? Would it be possible to saved to SharedPreference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you Should make a Pojo class of for your path variable, and then jsonify this class. and save this json to Sharedpref , thats it !!

Comment: I am not that familiar with JSON...I will first to research what JSON do ~ thx